# Autowired in a RowMapper implementation sets null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, rowmapper

I have the following RowMapper (ChallengeRowMapper) Implementation, in which I am trying to inject another RowMapper (ClaimsViewRowMapper):

```
  public class ChallengeRowMapper implements RowMapper<Challenge> {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("claimRowMapper1")
        private ClaimsViewRowMapper clMapper;
         .
         .
         @Override
    public Challenge mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("clMapper is:"+Boolean.toString(clMapper==null));//this prints true
         Challenge c=(Challenge)clMapper.mapRow(rs, rowNum); //getting NPE here
     }


    }
```

@Autowired is not working for some reason and clMapper is set as NULL.
Here is the other RowMapper which is annotated as @Component.

```
@Component("claimRowMapper1")
public class ClaimsViewRowMapper implements RowMapper<Claim> {
}
```

Another point to be noted here is Challenge extends Claim. Both the rowMappers are in the same package. And this package is under the component scan path as other DAOs in the package are working correctly with Autowired.
Can anyone please explain why the autowiring isn't working here?

Answer (score 0):

Did u annotate class ChallengeRowMapper with @Component?

Comment: can you tell me what is the need for annotating ChallengeRowMapper? I only need ClaimsViewRowMapper to be injected.